# Yii Framework - passing filename from url to Controller Action

Tags: variables, pdf, controller, yii2

I am currently able to download pdf files via a controller, without a view by passing variables to the controller via a link:

```
controller/action?customer=12345&fileid=6789
```

and I would like to be able to download the same files via a link like:

```
controller/action/12345/6789.pdf
```

so that browsers can open the file instead of download.

Is this possible?

Would an alternative fix be that I change php header and read the file?

Comment: Changing URL is pretty easy, but one question, can we pass here additional param in get request (or you want exacly same URL as you pasted here)?

Comment: I want the browser to assume it's a pdf file. The URL needs to look like that for the browser to open the file instead attempt to download. 12345 and 6789.pdf are the params.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The answer was staring at me in the face when I looked for the answer on their [guide-runtime-routing docs page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules).

The idea is play around with the URL rules and PHP headers to achieve a desired effect.